# ListView selected item drawable

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem in my ListView. I want to change the background of selected item when I select it to a custom drawable that I have,  but it doesn't work.

I want to have this effect as in the image to be the selecteditem

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/selected_item"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

And this is the text of list_row

```
<!-- this layout is used to view row of category list and resturant list  -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/txt_category_row" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:textColor="@color/BLACK"
    android:layout_height="55dp" 
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/hello" 
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

And this the ListView `code.xml`:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list_category" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="184dp" 
    android:dividerHeight="2px"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"  
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:divider="@color/Gray"  >
```

Answer (score 10):

In touch mode there is no selected or focused state.

However, you can have a checked state (even without a checkbox) and use that to change properties upon "selection". In your java code where you set up to display your list add this line after you define the listview:

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Then in your state list XML change this:

```
android:state_selected="true"
```

to this:

```
android:state_activated="true"
```

So now you should have:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:state_activated="true"  
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected_item"/> 
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
</selector>
```

And finally, set the background for your row view to point to your selector file:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/txt_category_row"  
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:textColor="@color/BLACK" 
    android:layout_height="55dp"  
    android:padding="10dp" 
    android:text="@string/hello"  
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector" />
```

You didn't give a name for your state list XML so I just used "item_selector".  You should replace that with whatever the name of that file actually is.

Comment: nothing is working with me .. my problem that i want to leave the selected item with it's new background after the selection and when i change the position it'll change with it and the text color.. please any help :((

Comment: So you want multiple ones?   Hence it to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE (I think that's the right one, I'm not at home to double check.

Comment: no you misunderstand me ,whaat i mean that is when i select on item its background and text color changed till i select another item the..the new selected item will take the effect of the background and text color and the old item become normal.. what i have now that the selected item just appear when i select it and gone when i remove my finger..can you help me to solve this problem.. thank you

Comment: That's what I gave you in my answer.  If you set the background to use the drawable state-list and set the list to CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, when you touch an item it will change the backgroudn color and stay that way until you touch another item.  I've edited my answer to try and make it clearer for you.

Comment: @Barak Hoops. You saved me Barak. working very fine. Thanks for this wonderful answer. Feeling like i should upvote your answer. Guess Basant should accept this answer.

Comment: Well, This is not working if adapter list item parent view has any onclickListener. :-(

Answer (score 1):

You should use CheckableFrameLayout as list item view. You can find it here - [CheckableFrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/CheckableFrameLayout.html)

You can see there, that when you click the list item, it changes background drawable to anything you want.

Answer (score -2):

```
dynamicListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
       //arg1 will give you that view   
       arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); 
    }
});
```

Comment: it's works but when i select another item the brevious view stay selected ..can u help