# how to show detail data contact by click name in listview android?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, simplecursoradapter, contactscontract

contactmanager.java

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ContactEditor.class);
    String projection = new String(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
    i.putExtra(projection, ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
    startActivityForResult(i, 2);
}
```

ContactEditor.java

```
private void populateFields(){
    if (mRowId != null)
    {
        Cursor address = mDbHelper.fetchContact(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(address);
        mContactNameEditText.setText(address.getString(address.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        mContactPhoneEditText.setText(address.getString(address.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));

    }
}

public Cursor fetchContact(long rowId)throws SQLException
{
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null); 
    if (cursor != null)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
     return cursor; 
}
```

i dont know how to fill mContactNameEditText(EditText) with name selected in listview at ContactManager.java
is there another way for getting contact detail,such : name,phone etc. by clicking name in listview?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10107068/1289716

Answer (score 0):

```
public void readContacts(){
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
               null, null, null, null);

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
           while (cur.moveToNext()) {
               String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
               String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
               if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                  // System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                   // get the phone number
                   Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                          new String[]{id}, null);
                   while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                         String phone = pCur.getString(
                                pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                  //       System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                   }
                   pCur.close();

                   get email and type

                  Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                           null,
                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                           new String[]{id}, null);
                   while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                       // This would allow you get several email addresses
                           // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                       String email = emailCur.getString(
                                     emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                       String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                                     emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                     System.out.println("Email " + email + " Email Type : " + emailType);
                   }
                   emailCur.close();

                   // Get note.......
                   String noteWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                   String[] noteWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                           Cursor noteCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, noteWhere, noteWhereParams, null);
                   if (noteCur.moveToFirst()) {
                       String note = noteCur.getString(noteCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE));
                     System.out.println("Note " + note);
                   }
                   noteCur.close();

                   //Get Postal Address....

                   String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                   String[] addrWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
//              Cursor addrCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
//                      null, null, null, null);
              Cursor addrCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                      null, addrWhere, addrWhereParams, null);

                   while(addrCur.moveToNext()) {
                       String poBox = addrCur.getString(
                                    addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
                       String street = addrCur.getString(
                                    addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
                       String city = addrCur.getString(
                                    addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
                       String state = addrCur.getString(
                                    addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
                       String postalCode = addrCur.getString(
                                    addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
                       String country = addrCur.getString(
                                    addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
                       String type = addrCur.getString(
                                    addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));

                       // Do something with these....

                   }
                   addrCur.close();

                   // Get Instant Messenger.........
                   String imWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                   String[] imWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                   Cursor imCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                           null, imWhere, imWhereParams, null);
                   if (imCur.moveToFirst()) {
                       String imName = imCur.getString(
                                imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA));
                       String imType;
                       imType = imCur.getString(
                                imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE));
                   }
                   imCur.close();

                   // Get Organizations.........

                   String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                   String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                   Cursor orgCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                               null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);

                   System.out.println("Organization");

                   if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) {
                       String orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY));
                       String title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));

                       System.out.println("Organization = "+ orgName);
                       System.out.println("Title = "+ title);
                   }
                   orgCur.close();
               }
           }
      }
   }
```