# Get the child item of custom list view

Tags: android

I have created one custom list view item for my application. Suppose for any click evet I need a particular child from the list view, how can I get that?

Any link or any help is appreciated.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10107068/1289716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have one custom list view (say lv). Then implement one onItemClickListener as below -

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // Let's suppose the custom list View has one textview
            TextView tv = (TextView) lv.getChildAt(position);
        }
    });
```

Here position helps you to recognise the item which has been clicked by the user. For each item you want to work with, you can get that in similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the child data item from the backing adapter.

Just use `ListView.getAdapter` and then `ArrayAdapter.getItem` with the position fed in from your `OnItemClickListener` (assuming you have set this).

If you make changes to the data item, remember to call `notifyDatasetChanged` on the adapter to display the changes. Try not to manipulate the views directly as this can lead to issues with view recycling.

Answer (score 0):

```
LIstView hv10;

hv10.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.hv10, bigList.get(i)));

RelativLayout rlv;

rlv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        text.setText("on click");
    }

}
```

Comment: You may want to put some explanation on the code.